# Conditional props type based on prop value

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to build a TextField element that uses either input or textarea depending on multiline prop value.

I am struggling to conditionally assign my element's prop type depending on the value of multiline.

For instance, the code below gives me an error

```
'multiline' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer.
```

Is there a way to do it?

```
const input = "input";
const textarea = "textarea";

export type TextFieldMultiline<Multiline extends boolean> = {
 multiline: Multiline,
}

export type TextFieldProps<Multiline extends boolean> = 
TextFieldMultiline<Multiline> & (Multiline extends true ? React.ComponentPropsWithRef<typeof textarea> :
React.ComponentPropsWithRef<typeof input>)

export const TextField = ({multiline, ...props}:  TextFieldProps<typeof multiline>) => 
<> {multiline ? <input {...props}/> : <textarea {...props}/>}</>
```

Comment: Fixed - thanks for pointing out, also added basic implementation of the element

Comment: (Just a side note about that sample basic implementation, which I know is just a sample: Is there any need for that fragment? I'd probably just use `=> multiline ? ___ : ___;`... [And the conditional looks backward. :-) ])

Comment: You are right, the real code is a bit more involved, but same idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using a generic conditional type for your props type, use a discriminated union:

```typescript
type ReactTextAreaProps = React.ComponentPropsWithRef<"textarea">;
type ReactInputProps = React.ComponentPropsWithRef<"input">;

export type TextFieldMultiline =
    | ({ multiline: true } & ReactTextAreaProps)
    | ({ multiline: false } & ReactInputProps);
```

Then the component looks like this:

```typescript
export const TextField = (props: TextFieldMultiline) => {
    if (props.multiline) {
        const { multiline: _, ...rest } = props;
        return <textarea {...rest} />;
    }
    const { multiline: _, ...rest } = props;
    return <input {...rest} />;
};
```

Usage examples:

```typescript
// Valid, allows `textarea`-specific `rows` prop, since `multiline` is `true`:
const a = <TextField multiline={true} rows={10} />;

// Valid, allows `input`-specific `pattern` prop, since `multiline` is `false`:
const b = <TextField multiline={false} pattern="\d+" />;

// INVALID, `multiline` is `true` and `textarea` doesn't have `pattern`:
const c = <TextField multiline={true} pattern="\d+" />;
//                                    ^^^^^^^−−− Error: Type '{ multiline: true; pattern: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & TextFieldMultiline'. Property 'pattern' does not exist on type...

// INVALID, `multiline` is `false` and `input` doesn't have `rows`:
const d = <TextField multiline={false} rows={10} />;
//                                     ^^^^−−−−− Error: Type '{ multiline: false; rows: number; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & TextFieldMultiline'. Property 'rows' does not exist on type...
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AocmATzCUWJgBUkAPGAQSJQAUcwAznAC8DdDAB0AYVyQAdkjkw+EQQHVgMABbJMAHnww2MFN3wA+CjTpiMASTlgArsv5DRycdNkQFSleqaOkj6+MCOLhYU5GyQsHDW9CzsAGLASAA2ACYAsk4ZMMAZ4fTC5HAVcAA+cAAUAN5wIPmFxQoAXAlQTvQAvnAAZLbMxlyoAQIAlOWVNQ1NLUUlnZgoGQJ9g8MOzq6qU9Gx0PBovgLwyTBpmVkidWBunZfX2XkFSwqTIuZw9TMVwEw9zcEma7zaSC+f0qMLgpzk51+C3ByzgAH0ADRwCQ4oiI-qiB77CiwypEGBOKByOB6IzsUyoX44iR4mD9AD0ln+cF63PhiMaYNaqMx2NxSHxdyJghJZKQFKpNPCuyZ4vOHK5vWi7PZcAAamtgFksWsMhAAO5CAAGdJM3CtAFoBHQ0IDgGg4FacJarXBpViBOE0PQrUKPkhfcBrTBuhH2uR+fAUHc9M90tlkcKFMJ6jGev1vQIcwBGAAMGu1uoNxWNcFNFutypcjudSFdmHdnrAKBgRipvv9cEDcmDnrDEMj1tW6zjCbO8AARim0zdM+Gc9ONv1u72kFThPgADpZADU+DgnMrcDsADk9RwADJ2AAiWNDiwncCjnrzEbrcluG1jAZFBfSyCAJTkAByeAtBQAA3EMdz7OQrXjRM4WXYwXluccShzX9tx7FCD2PM8Ly5cgdWvO9HxfN88IUSdPU3P8UAAz0mxgMCIIEaDYIQkNCzQucEXgW5RFTbD01wj98PqViCwbEtywoiggA)

On the face of it, you'd think you could move the destructuring to the parameter list or the top level of the component function (which is basically the same thing), but TypeScript's flow analysis can't track that `multiline` being true narrows the type of `rest` when you do that ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-ACA0ohRVwDM8ExzaC+wiGBEOQm54HQrCA2rfCtyzeBURIg8i24pBTzWc9+XtGt6gbJsKCAA)). With the above, it can.

---

I wouldn't do it, but if you really wanted to avoid that repeated destructuring, you could use type assertions [like this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AocmATzCUWJgBUkAPGAQSJQAUcwAznAC8DdDAB0AYVyQAdkjkw+EQQHVgMABbJMAHnww2MFN3wA+CjTpiMASTlgArsv5DRycdNkQFSleqaOkj6+MCOLhYU5GyQsHDW9CzsAGLASAA2ACYAsk4ZMMAZ4fTC5HAVcAA+cAAUAN5wIPmFxQoAXAlQTvQAvnAAZLbMxlyoAQIAlOWVNQ1NLUUlnZgoGQJ9g8MOzq6qU9Gx0PBovgLwyTBpmVkidY3NBUsKADRwEh9E53C9nZfX2TyTzaSEmInMcHqMwqRBgTigcgWwJK0MqFQA-HA9EZ2KZUJCPhIvvAUEJPBhLmNeG5+gB6cyotGdPThXYEz5Ib6k7YRPaCOmWci9aK02lwABqa2AWTeawyEAA7kIAAY4kzcZUAWgEdDQwEwwDQcGVOCVyrgYH4bwE4TQ9GVj1aJXNwBVMG6SGV7XIpzkXLuen+6WySKdCmE9XdPX6poEEYAjAAGAUisWS4oyuByxUq1kuLU6pB6g1G5VgFAwIwI82W1TW232x3PT1wV3G1brT3e33fABGAaDN1DzYjHY2-XLlaQCOE+AAOlkANT4OD01NwOwAOXFHAAMnYACJvB2LEEut0e80oOS3VXGPEoc1ZCCcuQAcngWhQADd7ZOq3IXo+mcJwDsYAK3E2IIRlGSAThWAGzguy6roK5Cihu257oex5Qc6rYqmOLbXreeYwE+L4CO+n4-vasZAT28C3KIgbgcGkGniUo5rOOcCxgmyaoRQQA):

```typescript
export const TextField = ({ multiline, ...rest }: TextFieldMultiline) => {
    return multiline
        ? <textarea {...rest as ReactTextAreaProps} />
        : <input {...rest as ReactInputProps} />;
};
```

*(Note that there's no need for the fragment wrapper in the question.)*

I generally prefer solutions without type assertions as they're less fragile (or rather, they're less *silently* fragile — when they break, they make noise about it ), but it's a judgement call either way.

---

Finally, **if** you had a reason you couldn't change your props type to a discriminated union and you had to stick with the generic conditional type, you could make your component function generic to avoid the circular issue with the type of `multiline`. But in that case, I don't think you can avoid the type assertions in the implementation:

```typescript
type ReactTextAreaProps = React.ComponentPropsWithRef<"textarea">;
type ReactInputProps = React.ComponentPropsWithRef<"input">;

export type TextFieldMultiline<Multiline extends boolean> = {
    multiline: Multiline;
};

export type TextFieldProps<Multiline extends boolean> =
    TextFieldMultiline<Multiline> &
        (Multiline extends true
            ? ReactTextAreaProps
            : ReactInputProps);

export const TextField = <Multiline extends boolean>({
    multiline,
    ...props
}: TextFieldProps<Multiline>) => {
    return multiline
        ? <textarea {...props as ReactTextAreaProps} />
        : <input {...props as ReactInputProps} />;
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AocmATzCUWJgBUkAPGAQSJQAUcwAznAC8DdDAB0AYVyQAdkjkw+EQQHVgMABbJMAHnww2MFN3wA+CjTpiMASTlgArsv5DRycdNkQFSleqaOkj6+MCOLhYU5GyQsHDW9CzsAGLASAA2ACYAsk4ZMMAZ4Uh6eQVFJXDGillCAEYQEBmocuYicADe5HC9cCD5hcUKAFxw5UMlFAC+0bHQ8IlwyTBpmVkBAmWDlQrV7LUNTS0obSI9fStr2RO7pbfDSO0AZBd9fQAUD1U1cnUJUCcSDe71BAH5bMxjFxUJsQaC+mNPPYIq5VAIAJRzVhxeBoXwCeBXdLZDrbCqPfZGP5HZqtcwfbrvAYUkoAGhBEi5YDc5GmY2J6025MmCnMGJE7SZfSIMCcUDk-R2j3hfQheiM7FMqC6XIkPPRcBQQmRUPYMN4bmmcAA9OZVb0xnpws54J09QbBEaTYwHK7Nta7TNojabXAAGooYpZNlGjIZCAAdyEAANNSZuCmALQCOhoYCYYBoOApnDJlNwT2xgThND0FMs0VICvAVMwQHNkbkfFyQlGsmC0mNu7CTrtoHWssCUcARgADIHLJRQxGo8AY3GE8mSy6XNnc0h84XiymwCgYEYFRWq3Aa3I6yXh48W6nMFGBJ3uwT4PUB8ZrlkSqsgoo5vhkH7WmeF5IAqwj4AAOlkADU+C2ku5ArnYABy4YcAAMnYAAisYNsqJQviW47NkafyUcY2ooBWWQQEgAhyAA5PAWgoAAbvWUGXnIKZdj2fbFqIeiDoBT4lKOVGQeeglwYhKFoSGYbYbhBHEY+ZEKBRKZgR+FanIBKa7jATEsWxnFwNxfEllOwlfr28CARJUlAU2oHvkgk5JtOnTzouFBAA)

Comment: Almost... if I do it with my updated code, I am now getting incompatible types errors for the common props https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-ql7826?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: @GRZa - I've updated the answer now that the basic implementation is in the question. Thinking about it, we didn't really want a generic conditional type in the first place (unless for some reason not in the question).

Comment: Great! exactly what I need. TVM